# Unix network programming, Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I'm trying to write simple program with Unix sockets, my server program seems to work but client (which is almost the same) don't.
I get error "Address family not supported by protocol".

In fact i'm not sure if i can use it the way i do it, namely just run those programs from two terminals, but i can't see what could be wrong with this.

library file network.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>


#define PORT_NUMBER_IN  14760
#define PORT_NUMBER_OUT 14761

typedef struct params_socket
{
        int domain_type; /*AF_UNIX lub AF_INET*/
        int link_type; /*SOCK_STREAM połączeniowy SOCK_DGRAM bezpoł. SOCK_RAW bezpośredni*/
        int protocol; /*zero - domyślny, inne w /etc/protocols*/
} params_socket;


typedef enum CONNECTION_TYPE
{
        CLIENT, SERVER
}CONNECTION_TYPE;


int create_socket(params_socket params);
int bind_socket(int my_socket, CONNECTION_TYPE connection_type);
int bind_socket_client(int my_socket);
int bind_socket_server(int my_socket);
struct sockaddr* get_address_structure_in();
struct sockaddr* get_address_structure_out();

int create_socket(params_socket params)
{
        int my_socket = socket(params.domain_type, params.link_type, params.protocol);
        if(0 > my_socket)
        {
                perror("socket");
        }
        return my_socket;
}

int bind_socket(int my_socket, CONNECTION_TYPE connection_type)
{
        int binded_socket = 1;
        struct sockaddr* address_structure;

        if(connection_type == SERVER)
        {
                address_structure = get_address_structure_in();
        }
        else if (connection_type == CLIENT)
        {
                address_structure = get_address_structure_out();
        }

        binded_socket = bind(my_socket, address_structure, sizeof(*address_structure));
        if(0 > binded_socket)
        {
                perror("bind");
        }

        return binded_socket;
}

int bind_socket_server(int my_socket)
{
        return bind_socket(my_socket, SERVER);
}

int bind_socket_client(int my_socket)
{
        return bind_socket(my_socket, CLIENT);
}


struct sockaddr* get_address_structure_in()
{

        struct sockaddr_in* address_structure = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        bzero((char *) address_structure, sizeof(*address_structure));
        address_structure->sin_family      = AF_INET;
        address_structure->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        address_structure->sin_port        = htons(PORT_NUMBER_IN);

        return (struct sockaddr*) address_structure;
}

struct sockaddr* get_address_structure_out()
{

        struct sockaddr_in* address_structure = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        bzero((char *) address_structure, sizeof(*address_structure));
        address_structure->sin_family      = AF_INET;
        address_structure->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        address_structure->sin_port        = htons(PORT_NUMBER_OUT);

        return (struct sockaddr*) address_structure;
}
```

server file(i guess it works, at least there are no errors)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "network.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    params_socket params = {AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0};

    int my_socket;
    int client_socket;
    int binded_socket;

    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    socklen_t address_size = sizeof(client_address);


    my_socket = create_socket(params);
    binded_socket = bind_socket_server(my_socket);
    printf("socket: %d\nbinded_socket: %d\n", my_socket, binded_socket);


    listen(my_socket, 5);
    client_socket = accept(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &address_size);
    if(0 > client_socket)
    {
        perror("connection");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client file, the only difference is that i use bind_socket_client instead of bind_socket_server, and later use connect

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "network.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    params_socket params = {AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0};
    int my_socket;
    int server_socket;
    int binded_socket;

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    socklen_t address_size = sizeof(server_address);


    my_socket = create_socket(params);
    binded_socket = bind_socket_client(my_socket);
    printf("socket: %d\nbinded_socket: %d\n", my_socket, binded_socket);


    server_socket = connect(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, address_size);
    if(0 > server_socket)
    {
        perror("connection");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: post the code directly instead of links...

Comment: as you wish, is it really better to read?

Comment: **note**: you don't need to cast `malloc` but you do need to check the returned pointer against `NULL`.

Comment: **curious**: why do you put code in a header file?

Comment: @iharob
The only way for the pointer to be `NULL` is when malloc fails, isn't it? 
And as far as I understand i need to use dynamically allocated memory if i want to return it as a pointer, and i want do it.    
It wasn't meant as a real header file, i just wanted to separate as much code from client/server files. I probably should make it as a .c file.

Comment: You really don't need to allocate it on the heap, you could pass the address of a local struct allocated on the stack, and that's how I usually do it, and I believe others do it that way too.

Comment: And yes it's when `malloc` fails, so you should check.

Comment: @iharob like this?
`struct sockaddr_in address_structure;
...  
return (struct sockaddr*) &address_structure;`

Comment: Where do you fill in `server_address` with an address?

Comment: @user1666938 you don't need to return it just `void fillAddress(struct sockaddr_in *s) { s->sin_family = AF_INET; ... }`, and then `struct sockaddr_in s; fillAddress(&s);`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks, of course i forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize `server_address`, add this in the client before connect

```
memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));

server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER_IN);
```